# Change the app icon for android and iOs in MAUI

Tags: c#, maui, maui-android

I am trying to change the app icon in a MAUI project but I am unable to do it.

I have added two images to the AppIcon folder ( I tried png and svg but none of them work)

And changed the csproj file to the new icons

`<MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\coolcoicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\coolcoiconbg.svg" Color="#000000" />`

I have cleaned the solution and the project.

However, when I try to play the app in the android emulator I have these error

```
Error   APT2260 resource mipmap/appicon (aka com.coolco.coolcoapp:mipmap/appicon) not found.
Error   APT2260 resource mipmap/appicon_round (aka com.coolco.coolcoapp:mipmap/appicon_round) not found.
Error   APT2067 failed processing manifest.
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e8RS.png)

Comment: Quick way to solve your problem, is to replace the default file, and not make up random names for icons. If you want to be creative anyway, you will need to learn how icons work for both platforms. Good place to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check the AndroidManifest.xml in the /Platforms/Andorid. And there is such one line code in it:

```
 <application ... android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" ...>
```

When you change the Appicon in the project's csproj file. You also need to change this line for the android. Such as:

```
 <application ... android:icon="@mipmap/coolcoicon" ...>
```

The `android:roundIcon` only used for the android 7.1. And you can delete it directly. I have tested this, and the app icon changed successfully.

You can also set the icon's file name as the default like H.A.H said.

Comment: Currently changing appicon and splash for iOS never succeed.

Answer (score 5):

For **iOS** what worked for me:

**Application Icon**

1. **!!!** **Application Icon** will **not** be deployed using **hot restart** iOS deployment from Visual Studio **!!!**
2. First try to use default **Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg** and **Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg** files without changing their **size** and replace content in those file with your own.
3. From MS docs: "While the project file -> **.csproj** declares which resources the app icon is composed from, you're still required to update the individual platform configurations with reference to those app icons"

3.1 In file Platforms\iOS\Info.plist create new entry:

```
<key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Assets.xcassets/appicon.appiconset</string>
```

Where **appicon** in appicon.appiconset have to match name of default **Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg** resource file mentioned in -> **.csproj**

4. Custom app icons needs to have **Build Action** set to **MauiIcon**. In Solution Explorer ( right click on file in Solution Explorer -> Properties -> Build Action = **MauiIcon**
5. In order to see changes delete Application in Device / iOS Simulator
6. Clean build
7. Try it now

7.1 Do not worked ? Try deleting **obj** and **bin** folder of project, be aware this might lead to **restoring Nuget Packages** ( right click on **Solution name** in Solution explorer -> Restore Nuget Packages)

7.2 Delete app from Device / iOS Simulator and try again

**Splash screen**

1. in -> **.csproj** file, works for me:

   ```
    <!-- Splash Screen -->
    <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splashscreen.png" BaseSize="400, 200" Color="White" />
   ```

1.1 File splashscreen.png have **Build Action** set to **MauiSplashScreen** ( right click on file in Solution Explorer -> Properties -> Build Action = MauiSplashScreen

1.2 From MS docs: The base size is specified with the BaseSize="W,H" attribute, where W is the width of the icon and H is the height of the icon. The value specified as the base size must be **divisible by 8**. The following example sets the base size:

1.3 Clean build and deploy

My project setup
Target platform .NET 7, Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.7.6

**Documentation**

Microsoft docs: Check **Platform-specific configuration** here in [Add an app icon to a .NET MAUI app project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=macios)

**Hints:**

**Custom App Icon and Custom Maui splash screen as PNG files**

1. When you have custom **.PNG** file with **custom size**, its sizes (width, height) should be divisible by **8**
2. Auto scaling of **.PNG** file might occurs if your pictures are big (sizes for Icon App differs based on platform, devices and place where they are shown in phone like desktop, settings). In order to do scale possible you need to set in -> **.csproj** file for MauiIcon or MauiSplashScreen **BaseSize** property same as your.png file itself have.

E.g. file have 1200 width and 1200 height both sizes are **divisible** by **8**. For app icon correct down scaling will happen because of BaseSize property

```
    <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon_custom.png" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg_custom.png" BaseSize="1200, 1200" />

    <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\appsplash_custom.png" Color="#FF7700" BaseSize="1200, 1200" />
```

Downscaling of .PNG files results in smoother picture than upscaling. Because of that you might think twice about size of your "base pictures". In case of .SVG files size is taken from content of .SVG file so there is no need to set particular size as in the case of .PNG files.

Comment: Thanks for all this. I am still having trouble.... Only difference I see is that I am using .NET 8. WHatever I try I still get the *** .NET app icon

Comment: Are you deploying to iOS (On iOS an valid build on mac device needs to be done in order to get appicon) or Android ? You have to also delete application from device before deployment in order to see differences.