# MAUI: 'Controls' could not be found and mipmap/appicon_round not found

Tags: maui

I am getting below errors when rebuilding the app in release mode before creating APK file.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   APT2067 failed processing manifest.
> MyProjectName   C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.43\tools\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets 214

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   APT2260 resource mipmap/appicon (aka com.companyname.MyAppName:mipmap/appicon) not found.

> This error is likely caused by an issue with the AndroidManifest.xml file or an Android manifest generation attribute in a source code file.  MyProjectName   E:\My Projects\MAUI\MyProjectName\MyProjectName\Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml   1

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   APT2260 resource mipmap/appicon_round (aka com.companyname.MyAppName:mipmap/appicon_round) not found.

> This error is likely caused by an issue with the AndroidManifest.xml file or an Android manifest generation attribute in a source code file.  MyProjectName   E:\My Projects\MAUI\MyProjectName\MyProjectName\Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml   1

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Controls' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  MyProjectName (net8.0-android)  E:\My Projects\MAUI\MyProjectName\MyProjectName\MainPage.xaml.cs    1   Active

I tried adding the appicon and appicon_round under Platforms/Android/Resources/mipmap, but no luck.

I am using Controls.UserDialogs.Maui - 1.3.0 for showing the userdialogs and due to that the last error is showing: The type or namespace name 'Controls' could not be found. I tried updating it to 1.5.0 but no luck.

My .Net version was 7 and I tried to update it to 8.

My VS(Windows) version is 17.9.0 Preview 1.0 also I tried on 17.8.1.

I tried creating a demo project with this issue, but in that there is no such issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> resource mipmap/appicon_round (aka com.companyname.MyAppName:mipmap/appicon_round) not found.

You can delete the `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round"` in the **\Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml** to resolve it. For more information, you can refer to my old answer about [changing the app icon for android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75668991/17455524).

> I am using Controls.UserDialogs.Maui - 1.3.0 for showing the userdialogs and due to that the last error is showing: The type or namespace name 'Controls' could not be found.

The Controls.UserDialogs.Maui doesn't support the Windows platform. So make sure the target platform is not windows. Such as target android:

[image]

And then, you can use `Controls.UserDialogs.Maui.UserDialogs.`

**Update:**

Change the appicon in the maui:

Delete the default icon file and rename your icon file as appicon.svg in the **Resources\AppIcon** folder. Then the appicon will be changed.

Or Delete the default icon file and put your icon file in the **Resources\AppIcon** folder and set its build action as **MauiIcon** such as myicon.svg.

And in the csproj, you will find:

```
<MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\myicon.svg" />
```

And then change the icon in the **\Platform\Android\AndroidManifest**:

```
<application ... android:icon="@mipmap/myicon" ...>
```

Don't forget to delete the `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round"`.

Comment: mipmap/appicon not found error is also there, should I remove that line from manifest?

Comment: For the UserDialogs, where should I set the target as android? Below is my release mode configuration. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lyj8h.png

Comment: @MatthewPans 1. Yes, you can just remove the `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round"` from manifest. 2. Please see the red area in my picture.

Comment: if I remove the app icon form manifest the android launcher icon is the default android icon. I have already added `<MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" Color="#FFFFFF" />`  in project.csproj file

Comment: Why is the ForegroundFile same as the MauiIcon? You can remove the `ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" Color="#FFFFFF"`. And did you read the link I provided? @MatthewPans

Comment: And did you delete the default android icon file? @MatthewPans

Comment: From where I need to delete the default android icon?

Comment: Just delete the default appicon in the `Resources\AppIcon` folder and put your appicon file in it. And set your icon file's build action as `MauiIcon`. @MatthewPans

Comment: You used the `<MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ` is the default icon. You need to change it to your icon file. @MatthewPans

Comment: You can read the official document about [the appicon in the maui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android). @MatthewPans

Comment: I show the details about change icon. You can check the update part in my answer. @MatthewPans

Comment: If I add `android:icon="@mipmap/myicon"`, I am getting error in release rebuild. Do we really need it on manifest file?

Comment: There is no change in the app icon after adding the svg icon on Resources\AppIcon folder.

Comment: Let me do it on a fresh project and I will update you here

Comment: In the fresh project the build was success.

Comment: The icon issue is still there. After removing the `icon` and `roundicon` from manifest a default launcher icon is set. But I have already set the AppIcon under Resources folder and it was working fine. The default icon is not the MAUI icon, it is a different icon, could you please check this screenshot and suggest how to solve it. I don't know from where it is setting.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkYuL.jpg

Comment: You have changed the icon and what's your issue now? @MatthewPans

Comment: I have had this issue myself and while looking around for an answer today, one thing helps. I read above that you have to set the icon to a MauiIcon. As soon as I did that the error went away and all the mipmap folders contained the properly scaled png images.